# SQL Server Profiler 2014 - how to get response?

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I know it was impossible in SQL Server Profiler 2005 to watch not only queries to database, but also see server response, and I'm wondering if it's possible in SQL Server Profiler 2014.

I'm using MS SQL Server 2014.

By server response I mean actual data rows, in response to SELECT, for example.

Comment: What is a "response" to you? Data or some events?

Comment: Note that SQL Trace/Profiler is a deprecated feature in favor of Extended Events so I would expect not expect enhancements in future versions.  Please clarify exactly what you mean by "server response".

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I updated question

Comment: If you wish to see what the server returns, just replay/rerun the traced selects